# Will data loss in AWS Redis cluster, if I will change instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I can't find information, on how to change my AWS Redis cluster instance type and won't lose my data in it?

Comment: Are you using redis elasticache or memorydb? If using elasticache, do you have persistence enabled? Just FYI redis elasticache is not fully durable, meaning it should never be the only place you store a particular piece of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer - No, Just don't reboot your master nodes.

Long Answer -
Elasticache implements somewhat of a replacement work-flow whenever you modify your clusters.
New Nodes will be launched in the backend with that modification (in your case, a different node type) and then they sync with the data in your current nodes.
Once the nodes are in sync, there will be change in the DNS records and modification will end.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheNodes.NodeReplacement.html

PS - always a good idea to take back up if its the cluster has critical data.

Cheers.